# Is there a Graph Minor Theorem for sets of graphs closed under (only) contraction?

Tags: graph-theory, forbidden-subgraphs

The [Graph Minor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem) tells us that any set of graphs that is closed under:

- Vertex Deletion
- Edge Deletion
- Edge Contraction

have a finite set of "forbidden minors", such that if a graph G contains at least one of those minors, you know that G is not within your set.

Is there an analogous [forbidden subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_graph_characterization) result for a set of graphs that is closed under edge contraction, but not closed under edge or vertex deletion?

Comment: The trouble you run into is: suppose your set contains a $4$-vertex clique, but not a $4$-vertex cycle. You're not going to be able to describe this by forbidding subgraphs. (I admit that if you're forbidding *induced* subgraphs, it's not yet clear to me that you run into the same problem.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Nice, good point. I'm okay with any finite set of forbidden things (such has induced subgraphs), I just linked forbidden subgraph because that was the closest thing I knew of